# Selecting specifical JSON data from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

```
var arr = [{"jack": "27483127"}, {"kenz": "17182134"}];
```

How to Can I select value of "kenz"?

Comment: Use `arr[1].kenz`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know WHERE kenz might be in this array.

```
const foundItem = arr.find(x=>x.hasOwnProperty('kenz')) //to capture the object
const foundItem = arr.find(x=>x.hasOwnProperty('kenz'))?.kenz //to capture the property
```

related reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to select!

```
var arr = [{"jack": "27483127"}, {"kenz": "17182134"}];
alert(arr[1].kenz)
```